# Assigning all values to array on the whole

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a Java program and I am using the following code for assigning some variables to an array:

```
for(int j=1;j<P.maxNetworkPow;j++){
    node.succList[j]=node.succ.succList[j-1];
}
```

Who knows how can I assign the all values to the array without `for` loop?

Comment: You could use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) something like `System.arraycopy(node.succ.succList, 0, node.succList, 1, P.maxNetworkPow-1)`

Comment: I don't get how people think this question is about filling an array, whereas OP clearly wants to copy from one array to another

Answer (score 6):

Use `Arrays.fill(node.succList, value)` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)).
If you want to fill array with one value.

If you want to init array from the other one use

`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

As user khelwood pointed out, you can use `System.arraycopy` to copy elements of a specific range from one array to another.

The method signature is:

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

- `src` is the source array which you want to copy
- `srcPos` is the starting position in the source array
- `dest` is the destination array you want to copy the data to
- `destPos` is the starting position in the destination array
- `length` is the number of array elements copied

For your case, it would be

```
System.arraycopy(node.succ.succList, 0, node.succList, 1, P.maxNetworkPow - 1);
```

Which means copy `P.maxNetworkPow - 1` elements from `node.succ.succList` at starting index `0` to the array `node.succList` at starting index `1`.

You have to be careful though, that `P.maxNetworkPow` is not bigger than the length of each array, or else you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

Use System.arraycopy. Example as follows:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SystemDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   int arr1[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   int arr2[] = { 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

   // copies an array from the specified source array
   System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr2, 0, 1);
   System.out.print("array2 = ");
   System.out.print(arr2[0] + " ");
   System.out.print(arr2[1] + " ");
   System.out.print(arr2[2] + " ");
   System.out.print(arr2[3] + " ");
   System.out.print(arr2[4] + " ");
   }
}
```

will output: 
array2 = 0 10 20 30 40